# npm read ECONNREST error while trying to install node-red on a siemens iot2040

Tags: npm, node-red

I'm trying to reinstall node-red on my iot2040. But everytime i've got the following error message. I checked already my proxy settings but i didn't got any. I have really no clue what to do or what to search for next...

```
root@iot2000:~# npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.41-yocto-standard
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "--unsafe-perm" "node-red"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/root/npm-debug.log
```

If anymore description or details needed let me know!
Best regards

^the npm-debug-log...

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '--unsafe-perm',
1 verbose cli   'node-red' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.10.3
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData node-red
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData node-red
9 silly mapToRegistry name node-red
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'node-red',
12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'node-red',
12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'node-red',
12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
13 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red
14 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red
15 verbose request no auth needed
16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 06:15:54 GMT+0000 (UTC)
17 verbose request id f444108786e9e35c
18 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red
19 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyconf-uba.siemens.net proxyconf-uba.siemens.net:80
20 info attempt registry request try #2 at 06:16:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)
21 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyconf-uba.siemens.net proxyconf-uba.siemens.net:80
23 info attempt registry request try #3 at 06:17:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)
24 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyconf-uba.siemens.net proxyconf-uba.siemens.net:80
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:176:17)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at connectErrorNT (net.js:1021:8)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for node-red { Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyconf-uba.siemens.net proxyconf-uba.siemens.net:80
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:176:17)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at connectErrorNT (net.js:1021:8)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
27 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
29 silly install printInstalled
30 verbose stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyconf-uba.siemens.net proxyconf-uba.siemens.net:80
30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:176:17)
30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
30 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
30 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
30 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
30 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
30 verbose stack     at connectErrorNT (net.js:1021:8)
30 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
30 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
31 verbose cwd /home/root
32 error Linux 4.4.41-yocto-standard
33 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "--unsafe-perm" "node-red"
34 error node v6.10.3
35 error npm  v3.10.10
36 error code ECONNRESET
37 error network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyconf-uba.siemens.net proxyconf-uba.siemens.net:80
38 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
38 error network and is related to network connectivity.
38 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
38 error network
38 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
38 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 19 of the log file, this is a problem with the HTTP proxy that npm is trying to use to reach the web.

It says that `proxyconf-uba.siemens.net` can not find IP address of `registry.npmjs.org` in order to proxy the request to download a package.

You will need to talk to your network administrator.